# Paypal Redirect MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I'm attempting to integerate to Paypal and currently I'm stuck trying to work out whether I'm sending the customer to the correct URL for paypal. Essentially what I am doing is I return a page a form with hidden tags. Once the document has loaded it will javascript is being executed to submit the form.

The sandbox url that is being used for the post action is: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @action = @Model.PayPalURL }))
{

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cmd)
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shopping" value="1"/>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.business)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.no_shipping)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.@return)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cancel_return)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.notify_url)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.currency_code)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item_name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.amount)

}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(this.document).ready(function () {
        var frm = $("form");
        frm.submit();
    })
    </script>
```

When the page is redirected it takes me to sandbox, and when I login as a one of the test account its as if I'm logging into the paypal rather than processing an checkout function (I'm saying this from experience of using the expresscheckout at other sites and the documentation on paypal). Once logged it shows the overview of the account, like going www.paypal.com and logging in directly. Due to this, I'm unable to confirm the payment, and unable to test out the return/cancellation redirects.

If you could advise as to what I'm doing wrong here it would be great.

Comment: what is your model.cmd value? 
I can repro if I pass an unrecognised value.

Sample: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=click&amount=10&business=usmars_1349277396_biz@paypal.com&lc=EN&item_name=Test&rm=2

(cmd=click instead of cmd=_xclick)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying it's x_click

Comment: I tried click instead of the x_click and I received the following: "You have requested an outdated version of PayPal. This error often results from the use of bookmarks."

Comment: Hey thanks for the hint, I used _xclick and it gave me what I was looking for. Did you mean to have that the other way around ?

Comment: no, my link was a repro of your issue. Sorry for the confusion - been on twitter for too long, so the comment may have been a bit too short for SO standards ;)